# Can I seal my bath overflow waste with silicon, from the inside?

Tags: plumbing, leak, sealing

We have a freestanding bath https://victoriaplum.com/product/mode-harrison-freestanding-bath-1790-x-810

Unfortunately, we cannot gain access to the underside and when it drains water is leaking through the ceiling.

This began when the bath was overfilled and water ran down the overflow seemingly draining into the floor/ceiling. Since then when water naturally flows through the plug it appears to be flowing back into the overflow pipe and into the ceiling.

What would be the best product to inject down the plug into the overflow pipe? Silicon? Or expandable foam? Would sealing the pipe from the inside work?[image]

Comment: normally, the overflow in these types of sink and basin has the overflow cavity channel into a drain pipe that has a hole in the side of the pipe.  It appears that the drain or the downspout has become loose.  You might try using a slot wrench and see if you can tighten the drain from the topside.  The best way to fix the issue is cut the ceiling and reconnect the drain pipe correctly.  I don't think any mixture pour into the overflow hole will adequately fix the problem.

Comment: You might try an experiment to see where the leak is . Try only a few inches of water and drain, then maybe 1/2 full and drain, 3/4 full and drain if only the upper level causes the leak it may be a slip fitting that came loose at least you would know the height of the leak, if those tubs are like some cast plastic sinks the overflow is glued in place and that glue lets go sometimes, I hope this is not your problem but it might help to know how high up the leak is.

Comment: @Programmer66 yes that sounds exactly like what's happening. Unfortunately I'm unable to move the bath as it weighs a ton. I was wondering (as I can see it) whether I could seal the overflow connection through the plug hole as I can see the water flowing back

Comment: Also worth noting the ceiling is overboard artex with lovely asbestos, so would rather not go in that way.

Comment: You cannot move the tub as there are foot lock fixtures to prevent it from moving.  If it moved, it would break the drain connection.  Didn't the installer install the tub drain through the ceiling during installation?  Also try Ed Beal ideal of just running water and see if it is leaking just through the drain.

Comment: No, I believe it was purely placed, installed then silicone run around one side

Comment: The leak must be beneath the bath as it leaks when drained from the plug now

Answer (score 2):

It will **not** work.

You will need to find the exact cause of the leak (e.g. disturbed slip-joint fitting, cracked tube, fitting pull-out, bad gasket, etc.) and fix it proper. If it is "freestanding" then the overflow should be accessible unless it is concealed in a skirt. If it's concealed... time to disconnect the supply and drain and tip that b^*ch up...

Comment: Tip it up will not help,  the connection to the drain is in the ceiling joist below. Tipping up is just jerking the slip joint connection out.  How would you put the pipes back in and tighten the nuts as you lower the tub back down.   You have to open up the ceiling to gain access to the drain and p-pipes.  There is no access panel.

Comment: @Programmer66, rubbish mate, the drain connection is above the floor. The tub unit does not extend to the floor, it sits on legs and the skirt surround hides it all. Detach the drain strainer and overflow plate from inside the tub and you can move the whole unit. Did you look at the specifications? "How would you put the pipes back in and tighten the nuts as you lower the tub back down?"- you don't, all plumbing is set and tightened before placing the tub, then you screw in the strainer and overflow plate. I have installed this model, that is what needs done.

Comment: The plumbing rises to the bottom of the bath through a cutout in the floor. Although, the bath does have a built in skirt, has been siliconed to the floor and is too heavy to lift. Looking down the plug I can see the T where the overflow connects. With this I can see water running down the overflow connection when I drain the bath. This is where I was wondering if I could apply a bodge to seal the overflow.

Comment: Yes the connection is above floor level, but access is through the floor/ceiling.

Comment: And that was my first suggestion to tiethen the drain with a slot wrench.  But it is the T Connection that is loose.

Comment: Adam, please provide photo so we can see what model/stype you have.  tks

Comment: I've added a photo down the plug. The bath is the same one in the Victoria plumb link. When the bath drained I could see water flowing down the side pipe in the picture.

Comment: So back up the overflow, it seems to leak more if I take the plug off the pop mechanism so not sure if that's allowing more water to flow up the overflow pipe

Comment: After further research, it appears you have a flexible hose connector from the tub to the waste drain.  Jimmy is correct- the only way to confirm where it is leaking is to tilt the tub on its side and retighten the connections.  Just because water flows into the overflow connections does not means it is leaking there.

Comment: Would I be able to prove whether the leak was the waste side or overflow side by specifically pouring water down each side of the plug?

Comment: Yes- by using a funnel with a hose on the end.  Make sure the hose is past the overflow connection.  Pour water into the Funnel-hose slowly.  You don't want the shallow p-trap to back the water back up the drain pipe.  After about a 1 or 2 L, you should be able to tell if the drain-waste line is leaking or not.